# 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer : What is the difference between both codes interpretation

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

Here, I try to do the one_hot encoding and first I use following code:

```
one_hot = one_hot.reshape((array.shape,n_labels))
print(one_hot)
```

and it give me error of :
**tuple object can not be interpreted as integer** and then I see other solution and the code will be :

```
one_hot = one_hot.reshape((*array.shape,n_labels))
print(one_hot)
```

and the issue will be solved , so what is the difference between both, I mean what happens when I use (*array.shape,n_labels) instead of (array.shape,n_lables). I am confused and can not find it . Please help me!, thank you in advanced.

Comment: In the second one you unpacking the `tuple` so, you are directly accessing the integer variables.

Comment: If you 
print(array.shape,n_labels); 
print(*array.shape,n_labels)
you will see differents

Answer (score 1):

The `*` operator converts the list to single arguments.

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(l)
```

will output

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

But

```
print(*l)
```

will output

```
1 2 3
```

Imagine it the following way: The call without `*` would be equivalent to `print([1, 2, 3])` and the second call would be equivalent to `print(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Start with an array, and its shape:

```
In [107]: y = np.ones((2,3))                                                                         
In [108]: y.shape                                                                                    
Out[108]: (2, 3)
In [109]: (y.shape,4)                                                                                
Out[109]: ((2, 3), 4)
In [110]: (*y.shape,4)                                                                               
Out[110]: (2, 3, 4)
```

Which of those `Out` will work in a `reshape` expression?

### ans

```
In [111]: np.arange(24).reshape(Out[110])                                                            
Out[111]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
In [112]: np.arange(24).reshape(Out[109])                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-bf548c3c6f2e> in <module>
----> 1 np.arange(24).reshape(Out[109])

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This one works as well:

```
np.arange(24).reshape(y.shape + (4,))
```

Can you figure out why?